# When an Abelian group is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let G be a finite abelian group.It contains a non trivial subgroup which is contained in every non trivial subgroup.Then G must be cyclic.
This is a problem of Herstein book(Pg 108,#11 2nd edition).I can't solve it Plz help me.

Comment: Suppose $G$ is not cyclic. Then it must be the direct product of two non-trivial subgroups.

Comment: @almagest Quaternion group with 8 elements is not a direct product of its proper subgroups

Comment: Nor is it abelian.

Comment: @Panja, $\;Q_8\;$ is **not** abelian...

Comment: yaa Q8 is not abelian...but then how it follows?

Comment: I was trying it someway differently.I got upto that G is a p-group,Where the subgroup of order p is unique.but after that i am not getting any thing

Comment: You are correct. It is a tough problem if you are not allowed to assume the fundamental theorem for finite abelian groups. Because it is essentially the hard part of proving that theorem. Did you cover it in your bookwork?

Comment: @almagest No i did not know the proof.But i think it should be done with exponent argument,may be it requires some work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $H$ is that unique minimal subgroup of $G$. Then for any $g\in G$:

1. $H\subset \langle g\rangle$ implying $H$ is cyclic,
2. Since $H$ is minimal $|H|=p$ is a prime,
3. $\langle g\rangle$ has order $p^n$ for some $n$,
4. $H=\langle g^{p^{n-1}}\rangle$

Now suppose that $h$ is an element of $G$ with the maximal order $ord(h)=p^m$, then $H=\langle h^{p^{m-1}}\rangle$. For any $g\in G$ with order $p^n\le p^m$, $g^{p^{n-1}}$ is a generator of $H$. So we can assume that
$$g^{p^{n-1}}=h^{p^{m-1}}.$$
It follows that 
$$(gh^{-p^{m-n}})^{p^{n-1}}=1.$$
If $gh^{-p^{m-n}}\ne 1$, then it generates a cyclic group of order at most $p^{n-1}$. This group again contains $H$, we can then proceed by reduction to show that $g$ is a power of $h$.

Comment: Why U r assuming g^p^n-1=h^p^m-1 it is not clear

Comment: $g^{p^{n-1}}$ is an element of order $p$ in $\langle h\rangle$, hence will have the form $h^{kp^{m-1}}$ for some $k$ not divisible by $p$. But then $h^k$ has the same order with $h$ and can play the role of $h$. It may be better just leave it $h^k$.

Comment: Yes i understand,good one thanks@Quang Hoang